# How do you solve this combination problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

Problem:

You have a hat filled with 6 red and 5 black cards. You pick 3 cards out of the hat. In order to win, you MUST pick 3 red cards OR 2 red cards and 1 black. How many ways are there for you to win?

How would I solve this by expressing my work with combinations?

Answer (score 2):

To get three black cards, you must pick three of six.  How many ways to do that?  To get two and one, you must pick two of six, then pair that with one of five.